# Imagem com fundo Transparente

Tags: php, javascript, imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer upload de uma imagem e deixar certa parte da imagem (o fundo) transparente. Pois gostaria de sobrepor essa imagem.

O manequim é a imagem fixa de fundo, e o vestido é a imagem que quero fazer o upload com o fundo transparente.

Comment: Sim. PHP? JS? qual linguagem gostaria de fazer isso?

Comment: Ainda não pensei na linguagem, mas PHP seria o ideal, pois tenho mais facilidade. Porem se em JS  for mais simples também poderá ser. @MarceloBonifazio

Comment: So mais uma coisa, como você define o fundo de uma imagem? No caso, um fundo branco?

Comment: Por exemplo vou ter uma imagem de fundo um, manequim, e quero colocar uma roupa por cima, mas a imagem não pode ter fundo branco, tem que ser transparente. @MarceloBonifazio

Comment: Então no fundo você so quer sobrepor uma imagem sobre a outra

Comment: Sim, preciso que todas imagens de roupas que upar para o sistema fiquem no mesmo estilo em que o vestido na imagem, pois a intenção é o usuario tirar uma foto de uma roupa, e colocar ela sobre o manequim. @MarceloBonifazio

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29655/discussion-between-indaiara-ribeiro-and-marcelo-bonifazio).

Answer (score 2):

Para remover a cor branca de uma imagem você usar pode usar um script em php como o abaixo.

```
<?php 
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("imagemexemplo.jpg");
    $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $white);
    imagepng($img,'imagemexemploalterada.png');
```

É importante você notar que esse script irá remover somente o branco e não cores próximas do branco. Se a qualidade da imagem não for das melhores você vai ter que remover pigmentos próximos do branco. Para isso você pode fazer outras iterações das mesmas funções pegando a imagem de saída usando `imagrecreatefrompng(...)` e passando outros valores no lugar de `$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);`.

A a precisão do seu algoritmo vai depender muito da qualidade e iluminação onde as fotos são tiradas.

Por fim você vai precisar de um algoritmo para remover as áreas transparentes da sua imagem para facilitar na hora de centralizar no css.

Um problema nessa solução é o caso de uma roupa branca aparecer com transparência dentro da roupa caso remova muitas cores próximas do branco (esse é o pior caso que você deve testar).

Outro ponto importante sobre essas manipulações em imagens no php é o limite de alocação em memória que pode ser atingido se as fotos forem grandes (mas pode ser facilmente alterado no php.ini)